# Text overflowing div

Tags: css, overflow

EDIT: Wow, do I feel like a heel. This is quite possibly the dumbest question ever posted on the internet, ever. The whole problem is that I tried to fit one incredibly long word into a div, and it overflowed. Sorry I wasted everyone's time.

I'm totally new to CSS. I'm trying to put together a simple page with some columns, or divs. I can create the columns just fine, but when I add text to them, the text just overflows the columns/divs. How can I contain the text within the appropriate div?

In all the books/tutorials/sites I have studied, this issue has never arisen. So why is it a problem for me? What do people normally do that prevents this from being an issue in the first place?

I assumed the browser would move the text to a new line once it reached the end of the div.

Also, overflow: hidden is not what I'm looking for. I don't want to hide the overflow. I want to eliminate the overflow altogether. I just want the text to flow naturally within the bounds of the column.

How can I achieve this? I have tried text-align:center and text-align:justify and word-wrap: word-break, but I feel like I shouldn't need any of this, and they don't give me exactly what I want anyway. Or do I need one of them?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Here's the code for a representative div.

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
        <h2>Left Column</h2>
            <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfaf</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
width: 240px;
background-color: green;
}
```

The div is contained in another div which is positioned relative.

Comment: Show us your HTML and CSS

Comment: try word-wrap: break-word; and give a definite width to Div

Comment: use p or header tag for text. Set width for your div containing paragraph. use position:relative for the div.

Comment: And also please include your code ,, so we can help you better

Comment: use real text or something close to it like use in print: search for lorem ipsum

Comment: Based on your code I have added demo link and updated my code snippet in my last answer.

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```
.breakWord120  
{  
   max-width: 120px !important;  
   word-break: break-all !important;  
   word-wrap: break-word !important;  
   vertical-align: top;  
   line-height: 15px;  
} 

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="breakWord120"></asp:Label>
```

[how to wrap text in grid's column or in label without space](http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-wrap-word-in-radgrids-column-or.html)

Edit:

```
<div id="left">
        <h2>Left Column</h2>
            <p>asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
            asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfaf</p>
</div>
.......
.......
#left {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
max-width: 240px !important;  
background-color: green;
word-break: break-all !important;  
word-wrap: break-word !important;  
}
```

[Demo based on your code](http://jsfiddle.net/Dz469/)

Comment: wanna explain what asp and teletik have to do with anything?